# Multiline TextField in a XUL "Box" Element

Tags: user-interface, firefox, xul

I need to put something like a Textarea into a "box" element in XUL. It needs to be multiline. It's for an explanation frame.

Is that possible? I can't find anything on the MDC official site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "textbox" element to create both text fields and text areas (multiple lines) in XUL. To create a text area just set the multiline attribute.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Input_Controls:

```
<textbox multiline="true"
         value="This is some text that could wrap onto multiple lines."/>
```

Answer (score 1):

i think it is better using `<html:textarea></html:textarea>`

it is more like what he want

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/description) element.